# Can I combine these two regexes into a single regex? (Find `that` in `string` if `this` is anywhere in `string`)

Tags: python, regex

As input I have a series of long strings, which may or may not have the pattern(s) I'm looking for.  The strings that have the pattern(s) will have an identifier(s) somewhere in the string, but not necessarily directly preceding the pattern(s).  Currently I'm using this logic to find what I'm looking for:

```
droid_name = re.compile("(r2-d2|c-3po)")
location = re.compile("pattern_of_numbered_sectors_where_theyre_located")
find_droid = re.findall(location, string) if re.match(droid_name, string) else not_the_droids_youre_looking_for
```

`r2-d2` and `c-3po` won't be the same length.

Can I combine this logic into a single regex?  Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm looking for a one-line solution because I have a number of different types of information that I want to extract from various strings, so I'm using a dictionary with the regexes.  So, something like this:

```
regexes = {
    'droid location': re.compile("droid_location_pattern")
    'jedi name': re.compile("jedi_name_pattern")
    'tatooine phone number': re.compile("tatooine_phone_pattern")
}

def analyze(some_string):
    for key, regex in regexes:
        data = re.findall(regex, some_string)
        if data:
            for data_item in data:
                send_to_mysql(label=key, info=data_item)
```

EDIT:
Some sample strings are below.

Valid numbers will have the pattern: 9XXXX, which may also be written as 9XXX-X

I don't want to match the number 92222:

```
[Darth Vader]: Hey babe, I'm chilling in the Death Star.  Where are you?
[Padme Amidala]: At the Galactic Senate, can't talk.
[Darth Vader]: Netflix and chill?
[Padme Amidala]: Call me later on my burner phone, the number is: 92222.
```

Here, I want to match the number 97777, because the string contains r2-d2:

```
[communique yoda:palpatine] spotted luke skywalker i have.
[communique yoda:palpatine] with the droid he is.  r2-d2 we must kill.    
[communique yoda:palpatine] location 97777 you must go.
```

Another possible match because the string contains c-3po:

```
root@palpatine$ at-at start --target c-3po --location 9777-7
AT-AT startup sequence...
[Error] fuel reserves low, aborting startup.  Goodbye.
```

Don't want to match:

```
https://members.princessleiapics.com?username=stormtrooper&password=96969
```

Comment: Do you have some sample strings as well?

Comment: I edited my question to provide sample strings at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this highly depends on your actual strings. Assuming that `c-3po` or `r2-d2` will always be *before* the desired location number (am I correct here?) you could use for both your examples the following regex:

```
(?:c-3po|r2-d2)(?=.*\b(9\d\d\d-?\d)\b)
# looks for c-3po or r2-d2 literally
# start a positive lookahead
# which consumes every character zero or unlimited times
# looks for a word boundary
# and captures a five digit number with or without a dash
# looks for a word boundary afterwards and close the lookahead
```

Be aware that this only works in `DOTALL` mode (aka the dot matches newline characters as well). See a [working demo on regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/jI5rH6/1) (copy and paste your other strings to confirm the examples are working).

**Additionaly thoughts**: It might be better though to check if the strings `c-3po` or `r2-d2` occur in the chunks using normal python string functions and if so try to match the desired location number with the following regex:

```
\b(9\d\d\d-?\d)\b
# same as above without the lookahead
```